# Laravel Existing Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I want to validate the input if the client_id in inserting is existing from the other table

Table where **client_id** is selected if existing

```
Schema::create('cluster_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('cluster_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();

});
```

Table where i will insert the record if passed the validation

```
Schema::create('loan_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();


});
```

So in my Controller

Here is my rule

```
$rule = ['client_id'=>'required | numeric | exists:clients,id | exists:cluster_members,client_id'];
```

And this throws me this error

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id ' in 'where clause'**

Comment: Can you show inserts code where this SQL error happens

Comment: Im just using 
$model->save($request->all());

Comment: Both `cluster_members` and `loan_applications` have an `id` field try to change your validation rule to: `(..) exists:clients,clients.id (...)`. Sounds stupid but who knows? :)